# Flask API - post is list not dict

Tags: python, json, flask

I am trying to use native Flask to create an API, using request.get_json which I expected (from every tutorial or video I've looked at) would return a dictionary - but it is a list. It is harder to get the data out of a list than a dict.

The post is from a Powershell core script which reads a CSV file via import-csv, does a convertto-json, and invoke-webrequest with -ContentType "application/json"

I outputed the JSON in powershell, and put it into jsonlint.com - which said it was valid JSON. The opening (and closing) bracket made me look to see if it was a series of dictionaries within one list - which it is.

JSON fragment:

[
  {
    "PO": “12345678”,
    "Vendor": “BENZ”,
    "Warehouse": "BEZRS1",
    "ASIN": "B07ZLJ7DPG",
    "External ID": “1234567890”,
    “Catalog”: “90210”,
    "Title": “Persil“,
    "Window Type": "Delivery Window",
    "Expected Date": "02/17/2020",
    "Quantity Requested": “18",
    "Accepted Quantity": “18",
    "Received Quantity": "0",
    "Outstanding Quantity": "8",
    "Unit Price": “19.39",
    "Discount(%)": "0",
    "Unit Cost": “19.39",
    "Total Cost": “175.12"
  },
  {
    "PO": “987654321”,
    "Vendor": “BENZ”,

Powershell:

```
$payload = $file | convertto-json

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://127.0.0.1:5000/api -body $payload -method post -ContentType "application/json"
```

Flask (printing out for debugging):

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def get_order():
    data = request.get_json()

    print(type(data))

    purchaseorder = data[0]

    print(purchaseorder)

    return jsonify(data)
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `$payload`?

Answer (score 0):

So, each line from the CSV file was a dictionary put into a list.

```
for item in data:
    purchaseorder = item

    myline = purchaseorder

    purchaseorder = myline['PO']
```